# Hibernate: Joining Criteria

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Hi I need to do the following using Criteria

```
Select * from product pd, (Select productID pd1 from ... where ...) tpd1, 
(Select productID pd2 from ... where ...) tpd2
where pd.productID = tpd1.pd1 and pd.productID = tpd1.pd2
```

May I know if it is possible?

The original SQL was using IN conditions

```
Select * from product pd where productID in (Select productID pd1 from ... where ...) and 
productID in (Select productID pd2 from ... where ...)
```

but it takes too long to get the result, using the join SQL statement I was able to obtain my result faster.

any help?

Comment: Please post the explain plan for the original query.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're using Hibernate, you may have to do something like this, which should work ok if the number of expected matches are relatively low:

```
select *
from   product pd
where  pd.productID in
   (select productID
    from   product pd2
    join   tpd1 on (pd2.productID = tpd1.pd1)
    join   tpd2 on (pd2.productID = tpd2.pd2)
    where  tpd1....
    and    tpd2....
   );
```

I assume there is a unique index on `product.productID`.

Alternatively, you could try the EXISTS formulation which may or may not work better than your original query:

```
select *
from   product pd
where  EXISTS
   (select null from tpd1 where pd.productID = tpd1.pd1 and ...)
and    EXISTS
   (select null from tpd2 where pd.productID = tpd2.pd2 and ...)
;
```

Comment: I'm currently your suggested solution with hibernate criteria BUT is very lagging as some of the select statement has having by. I attempt to use SQL optimizer and it recommend using join table. The OUTLINER input for your suggested solution won't load but for the join table query it will load. One of reason is because of the huge amount of data returned.

Comment: You really need to post the Explain Plan for your query - even better, for all the suggested queries. Without the plan, all we can do is guesswork.